# Firebase Database does not work on android emulator

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app is checking if a certain data is in the Firebase Realtime Database with a addListenerForSingleValueEvent added to a database reference. The emulator in which i started the project works fine and retrieves the data perfectly but when i change the emulator (let's say i switch to PIXEL 3XL) the listener doesn't work. I've seen in another stackoverflow question that someone had the same problem and the database retrieved data but after a long time. Does anyone know why this happens? Should i keep on developing with the default emulator and not care about the realtime database not working on another emulator? Can you explain why this happening?

I use this in the manifest:
`...<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>...`

Gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle(Module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

Edit 1:
Added the code (It works on the default emulator,pixel 3, but not on another) The logs are just to see if the code is doing what it should.

```
DatabaseReference database, newRef;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
(...)
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
newRef = database.child(option).child(strSelectedYear).child(strSelectedMonth).child(strSelectedDay);
        newRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot d: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    hours.remove(d.getKey());
                    Log.i("hAI FRAAA", d.getKey());

                }
                String msg = "";
                for (int j = 0;j<hours.size();j+=1)
                    msg += " " + hours.get(j);
                Log.i("Free hours", msg);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: @a_local_nobody Just added the code.

Comment: Maybe it's because you are using a free version of Firebase? It sometimes stops working ;)

Comment: @LeoLeontev :) i don't really think so because it always works on the default emulator.

Comment: what is the android sdk used in the other emulator?

Comment: @PeterHaddad I'm really new to this. I hope the sdk is the same one as the API version of the emulator. Both (the one working and the one that doesn't) are 29

Comment: @LeoLeontev There is no difference between free/paid versions of Firebase in this respect. If you ever encounter such a problem, please open a question for it here, or [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: I answered the same question here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73387871/7072402

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do some more troubleshooting on your own to figure out what's going wrong. A few steps I would take:

1. Stop ignoring possible errors and implement `onCancelled`. At its minimum that should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.
2. Ensure the internet access works on the second emulator. So do other apps work?
3. [Enabling debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and check in the logcat output what is going on.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but unfortunately it is still not working. I've implemented onCancelled and ensured that emulator has internet acces. The thing is that, i think the listener is triggered but it takes a lot of time for this emulator to get the data, just like the person who posted this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50195049/firebase-android-works-on-the-emulator-but-not-on-the-device). I've also tried the answers people gave there but im really stuck.

Comment: Did you also enable debug logging and check where the time is going, as I said in step 3?

Comment: I did the logging debug and the app is working now. The problem was caused by a memtrack error so i had to uninstall the app from the emulator and install it again. I feel so dumb and spent like 3 hours working on this thing but at least it's working. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with this issue for a few days. Finally connecting my physical android device to computer fixed the issue for me. I guess the emulators internet connection is not as healthy as Firestore expects. The cause of the problem was the emulator for me.

Answer (score 0):

I hade same problem with latest Android Emulator Version, I just replaced with previews version and fixed my problem.

1. Go to Android SDK
2. Make Copy of Emulator
3. Download previews version of Android Emulator from [Emulator download archives](https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive)
4. Copy Emulator folder inside Android SDK
5. Copy package.json from old Emulator and replace version with new version: `<revision><major>31</major><minor>1</minor><micro>4</micro></revision>`
   That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. In my case with Firebase Remote Config and Crashlytics. On the emulator is stops after FirebaseApp initialization. (API 28, Pixel 2).
[image]

On the physical device it continues as expected.
[image]

**And just as I am writing the emulator continued and initialized the Firebase services.** It took 7 minutes and several attempts (without any interaction from my side).

See the log:
[image]